# Add a link to a Google calendar event

Tags: vba, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am looking to use VBA (or another programming tool) to automate the creation of Google Calendar events.  I'd like to include two URL links in the event description, but have been unable to create them (even manually).  I've seen articles about adding an href HTML tag, but the link only shows up in public calendars.  The only way I seem to be able to include a URL is if I get an invitation to an event from another user.  So two questions:

1. Confirm that there is no way to add a calendar event with a URL.  I don't want to use a public calendar, I want it to be in the description when I open the event in my calendar.
2. Confirm that invitations can be generated automatically.  It might be a pain, but my work-around might be to send bulk invitations (with the URL links in the description) to a calendar and accept the invitations.

Comment: Regarding question 1, the only option is, Once the event is created then when you do events.list, in the response, for each event you will see html link. You can access event through that option directly. For second question, do you mean generating script?

Comment: DalmTo - I'm surprised that there is no way to embed a calendar appointment link.  When I receive e-mails from people outside our Google domain, the e-mails often contain appointments, which I can add to my calendar just by clicking.  In response to your question, I am willing t write a script that generates e-mails (with calendar appointments) instead of using the Gmail interface.